# Integrate an exponential distribution

Tags: integration, exponential-function

One of my textbooks on phylogenetics keeps going further than I can follow with my 'college calculus'...a probability function is stated as

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\theta\tau}(\theta\tau)^d}{d!}e^{-\tau} d\tau $$

...and this is evaluated as

$$ = \left(\frac{1}{1+\theta}\right)\left(\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}\right)^d   $$

Could anyone help me with the intervening steps? I feel sure the answer must have something to do with the definition of e as the limit of 1/n!

Answer (score 2):

The integral is defined, not undefined

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\theta\tau}(\theta\tau)^d}{d!}e^{-\tau} d\tau$$

and can be rewritten as follows

$$\frac{\theta^d}{(\theta+1)^{d+1}d!}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}[(\theta+1)\tau]^d e^{-\tau(\theta+1)}d[\tau(\theta+1)]}_{=\Gamma(d+1)=d!}=\frac{\theta^d}{(\theta+1)^{d+1}}=\frac{1}{\theta+1}\Bigg(\frac{\theta}{\theta+1}\Bigg)^d$$

EDIT: assuming $d \in N$

Comment: @jimjim : it is understood that they are requesting a probability over $R^+$, I assumed...

Comment: Your assumption are good enough for me ;)

Comment: One should take care to mention explicitly that $d$ is a natural number, otherwise $\Gamma(d+1) \ne d!$

Comment: @Infinity_hunter : you are right. Specified in the edit